# How to find a period of time within a string in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was wondering if there was an easy way (using existing regex for instance) to find a period of time written in a string in JavaScript.

For example, if I have:

`var str = "This movie lasts 2 hr 14 min and is a great movie"`

I'd like to extract the substring `"2 hr 14 min"`.

**EDIT**

I only want to extract the substring representing the time. I don't want to format it to something like "2 hours 14 minutes". I just want to extract `"2 hr 14 min"`

Comment: I'm fairly new to javascript, could you please explain why you downvoted my post?

Comment: I'd guess the problem is that you don't describe the format of the text you want to parse. Having the `2 hr 14 min` example is good, but it's not enough. Should it also parse `2 hours 14 minutes`? What about `2"14'` ?

Comment: Now for the beginning of an answer : if you have control over how the time period will be represented in the input text, force a standard and use an existing parser of this standard. Otherwise, you will probably have to roll your own parser, which looks like it could be done with regexs

Comment: I actually just want to extract the substring "2 hr 14 min", I don't want to format it in any way

Comment: `2 hr 14min` has a format already. It's a specific way to represent what we know as two hours and fourteen minutes. Do you want to only parse this specific way to represent time periods, or are there others you did not talk about? How should days be represented if your time periods can reach that size? When given the string "2d 2h 14min 3s", should I just output "2h 14min" or the whole thing?

Comment: Thanks for the guiding questions Aaron. I only have to take care of this really specific format `2 hr 14 min`

Comment: I'd use a mini compiler. Split the sentence into tokens, and then build an AST from the result where you make sure that a number is to be followed by a time delineator. Then extract only the valid trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on string you provided, that's all you need.

```js
var text = "This movie lasts 2 hr 14 min and is a great movie";
var match = text.match(/(\d+( hr| min))/g);
console.log(match);
//Let's make it string
match = match.join(" ");
console.log(match);
```

## Edit

`match = "2 hr 14 min"`

## Edit2

New regex, now won't match any number.

Comment: This won't work. It will match any number in the string.

Answer (score 1):

This will get hours and minutes and not all the integers in the string. [Oen44's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43409319/3649914) will pick up random numbers in the string.

```
var str = "This movie lasts 2 hr 14 min and is a great movie"

var regexp = /([0-9])+ (hr|min)/g;
str = str.match(regexp);
```

output = "2 hr,14 min"

Comment: This is better, but it would also match `000 hr 000000 min` thought

Comment: Would also match `2 minor mistakes` and `3 hr people`

Answer (score 1):

**Try this one liner answer :**

```js
var text = "This movie lasts 2 hr 14 min and is a great movie";

console.log(text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("hr")-3,text.lastIndexOf("min")+3));
```

Comment: You probably mean `test.lastIndexOf("min")+3`, as it currently truncates `min` to `m`? Also, this does not check that `hr` and `min` are whole words and would return `3 hr people did 2 m` from `the 3 hr people did 2 minor mistakes`

Answer (score -2):

You can use substring for this.

var str = "This movie lasts 2 hr 14 min and is a great movie";var res = str.substring(17, 24); console.log(res);

Comment: The thing is: I don't know what the string is going to look like exactly

Comment: Very bad idea. Add more hours, and you will have different output.

Comment: It will return a string.try str.substring(17, 28); it will return "2 hr 14 min"

Comment: is the string dynamic?

Comment: Well, it could be "length: 12 hr 56 min" or something like that